# Retrieve exit code of processes launched with multiprocessing.Pool.map

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm using python `multiprocessing` module to parallelize some computationally heavy tasks.
 The obvious choice is to use a `Pool` of workers and then use the `map` method.

However, processes can fail. For instance, they may be silently killed for instance by the `oom-killer`. Therefore I would like to be able to retrieve the exit code of the processes launched with `map`.

Additionally, for logging purpose, I would like to be able to know the PID of the process launched to execute each value in the the iterable.

Comment: are you on Python2  or Python3?

Comment: I use mostly python 2.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're using `multiprocessing.Pool.map` you're generally not interested in the *exit code* of the sub-processes in the pool, you're interested in what value they returned from their work item. This is because under normal conditions, the processes in a `Pool` won't exit until you `close`/`join` the pool, so there's no exit codes to retrieve until all work is complete, and the `Pool` is about to be destroyed. Because of this, there is no public API to get the exit codes of those sub-processes.

Now, you're worried about exceptional conditions, where something out-of-band kills one of the sub-processes while it's doing work. If you hit an issue like this, you're probably going to run into some strange behavior. In fact, in my tests where I killed a process in a `Pool` while it was doing work as part of a `map` call, `map` never completed, because the killed process didn't complete. Python did, however, immediately launch a new process to replace the one I killed.

That said, you can get the pid of each process in your pool by accessing the `multiprocessing.Process` objects inside the pool directly, using the private `_pool` attribute:

```
pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
for proc in pool._pool:
  print proc.pid
```

So, one thing you could do to try to detect when a process had died unexpectedly (assuming you don't get stuck in a blocking call as a result). You can do this by examining the list of processes in the pool before and after making a call to `map_async`:

```
before = pool._pool[:]  # Make a copy of the list of Process objects in our pool
result = pool.map_async(func, iterable)  # Use map_async so we don't get stuck.
while not result.ready():  # Wait for the call to complete
    if any(proc.exitcode for proc in before):  # Abort if one of our original processes is dead.
        print "One of our processes has exited. Something probably went horribly wrong."
        break
    result.wait(timeout=1)
else:  # We'll enter this block if we don't reach `break` above.
    print result.get() # Actually fetch the result list here.
```

We have to make a copy of the list because when a process in the `Pool` dies, Python immediately replaces it with a new process, and removes the dead one from the list.

This worked for me in my tests, but because it's relying on a private attribute of the `Pool` object (`_pool`) it's risky to use in production code. I would also suggest that it may be overkill to worry too much about this scenario, since it's very unlikely to occur and complicates the implementation significantly.

Comment: You're right: when such problems arise, I get strange results. In the current code, processes are launched by a special loop. My idea was to replace this loop by a (much simpler) call to map. However your solution is about as complex as the current one so I don't think it's worth. Also, processes write their results to the disk (so I don't really need their result). However you answer is interesting.

Comment: Also of note here: [`concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor) does detect when a process has been killed unexpectedly, and will raise a `BrokenProcessPool` on any outstanding tasks when it happens. There is [a bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue22393) filed against `multiprocessing`, which has a working patch, to add this behavior to `multiprocessing.Pool` as well.

Comment: Billiard is a multiprocessing fork that seems to handle this case https://pypi.org/project/billiard/

Comment: @JAR.JAR.beans excellent find! thank you so much...I've been having exactly this problem with dying processes and I've been looking for a way to capture more info about the dead processes: this module does the trick nicely. Meanwhile I have filed a Python issue since I think this needs resolving in the standard library code: https://bugs.python.org/issue43449