# Python Multiprocessing: Crash in subprocess?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

What happens when a python script opens subprocesses and one process crashes?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18216437/311901

Will the main process crash?

Will the other subprocesses crash?

Is there a signal or other event that's propagated?

Answer (score 20):

When using `multiprocessing.Pool`, if one of the subprocesses in the pool crashes, you will not be notified at all, and a new process will immediately be started to take its place:

```
>>> import multiprocessing
>>> p = multiprocessing.Pool()
>>> p._processes
4
>>> p._pool
[<Process(PoolWorker-1, started daemon)>, <Process(PoolWorker-2, started daemon)>, <Process(PoolWorker-3, started daemon)>, <Process(PoolWorker-4, started daemon)>]
>>> [proc.pid for proc in p._pool]
[30760, 30761, 30762, 30763]
```

Then in another window:

```
dan@dantop:~$ kill 30763
```

Back to the pool:

```
>>> [proc.pid for proc in p._pool]
[30760, 30761, 30762, 30767]  # New pid for the last process
```

You can continue using the pool as if nothing happened. However, any work item that the killed child process was running at the time it died will **not** be completed or restarted. If you were running a blocking `map` or `apply` call that was relying on that work item to complete, it will likely hang indefinitely. There is a [bug filed for this](http://bugs.python.org/issue9205), but the issue was only fixed in [`concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor), rather than in `multiprocessing.Pool`. Starting with Python 3.3, `ProcessPoolExecutor` will raise a `BrokenProcessPool` exception if a child process is killed, and disallow any further use of the pool. Sadly, `multiprocessing` didn't get this enhancement. For now, if you want to guard against a pool call blocking forever due to a sub-process crashing, you have to use [ugly workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24396655/2073595).

**Note**: The above only applies to a process in a pool actually *crashing*, meaning the process completely dies. If a sub-process raises an exception, that will be propagated up the parent process when you try to retrieve the result of the work item:

```
>>> def f(): raise Exception("Oh no")
... 
>>> pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
>>> result = pool.apply_async(f)
>>> result.get()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 528, in get
    raise self._value
Exception: Oh no
```

When using a `multiprocessing.Process` directly, the process object will show that the process has exited with a non-zero exit code if it crashes:

```
>>> def f(): time.sleep(30)
... 
>>> p = multiprocessing.Process(target=f)
>>> p.start()
>>> p.join()  # Kill the process while this is blocking, and join immediately ends
>>> p.exitcode
-15
```

The behavior is similar if an exception is raised:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def f(x):
    raise Exception("Oh no")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=f)
    p.start()
    p.join()
    print(p.exitcode)
    print("done")
```

Output:

```
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/multiprocessing/process.py", line 267, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/multiprocessing/process.py", line 116, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: f() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
1
done
```

As you can see, the traceback from the child is printed, but it doesn't affect exceution of the main process, which is able to show the `exitcode` of the child was `1`.

Comment: It looks like the bug is still open and there are some unfinished attempts to fix it, the latest one being https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/16103