# Constantly running Pool of workers

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'm using `multiprocessor.Pool` to parallelize processing some files. The code waits for a file to be received, then sends that file to a worker using `Pool.apply_async`, which then processes the file.

This code is supposed to be always running, therefore I don't ever close the pool. This however causes the pool to consume a lot of memory over time.

The code is something like this:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    with Pool(processes=PROCESS_COUNT) as pool:
        while True:
            f = wait_for_file()
            pool.apply_async(process_file, (f,))
```

How can I prevent high memory usage from happening without closing the pool?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Added the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you allocate resources and you don't deallocate them be it number of [spawned processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(system_call)) or simply (a chunk of) memory, you'll have less resources for other tasks on your machine until you or your system willingly or forcefully deallocate them.

You may want to use `maxtasksperchild` argument for [`Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) to attempt killing the slaves e.g. if they allocate memory and you have a leak somewhere, so you save at least some resources.

> Note: Worker processes within a Pool typically live for the complete duration of the Pool’s work queue. A frequent pattern found in other systems (such as Apache, mod_wsgi, etc) to free resources held by workers is to allow a worker within a pool to complete only a set amount of work before being exiting, being cleaned up and a new process spawned to replace the old one. The maxtasksperchild argument to the Pool exposes this ability to the end user.

Alternatively, don't roll your own implementation of [`Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) because until you get there it'll be buggy and you'll unnecessarily burn the time. **Instead** use e.g. [Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html) ([tutorial](https://yimingstar.medium.com/python-multiproccessing-celery-bc48bb355d1f)) which hopefully even has tests for nasty corner-cases you might spend more time on than necessary.

Or, if you want to experiment a bit, [here is a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26247757/5994041) which provides steps to custom slave pool management.

Comment: I get that, but how do I deallocate the resources used by the worker when it finishes in this instance, without using `pool.close()`?

Comment: You don't really, unless you write your own (auto)scaler (high-level e.g. like in Kubernetes) by a custom measurement. [`Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) is basically a convenient wrapper for manual [`Process`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process) spawning. If you want to have scaling abilities, you'll need to implement them based on the logic you want it to behave in.

Comment: @user [ref for k8s autoscaler concept](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/) to give you an idea.

Comment: There is something I still don't get. Why are more and more resources allocated to the processes. When `process_file()` finishes running, shouldn't it's garbage be collected on the worker process, like it is on the main process?

Comment: @user That really depends on the implementation of `process_file` function **and** its dependencies. Some packages/people love to do context stuff as globals hence causing a leak perhaps even intentionally. In the approach like a pool of processes however, the leak is just scaled by the number of processes, which can make the leak huge.