# Python multiprocessing hangs indefinitely on completion

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to use Python's multiprocessing module to run an analysis on multiple samples in parallel. I'm using `pool.map_async` to spawn the function (called `crispr_analysis`) on a tuple of tuples for arguments (`zipped_args`). Each tuple within `zipped_args` is not empty, as that can cause multiprocessing to hang. Upon completion of the pool, it hangs and fails to move on to the rest of the script. I know that `crispr_analysis` finishes as it creates output files (generated with `with` statements, so they're closing properly); I can browse said files and they are complete. I never see the debug message for sorting the results, and the program never terminates.

```
try:
    #   Use map_async and get with a large timeout
    #   to allow for KeyboardInterrupts to be caught
    #   and handled with the try/except
    timeout = max((9999, 600 * len(fastq_list)))
    logging.debug("Setting timeout to %s seconds", timeout)
    res = pool.map_async(crispr_analysis, zipped_args) # type: multiprocessing.pool.MapResult
    pool.close()
    results = res.get(timeout)
except (KeyboardInterrupt, ExitPool) as error: # Handle ctrl+c or custom ExitPool
    pool.terminate()
    # pool.join()
    if isinstance(error, KeyboardInterrupt): # ctrl+c
        sys.exit('\nkilled')
    elif isinstance(error, ExitPool): # My way of handling SystemExits
        sys.exit(error.msg)
    else: # Shouldn't happen, but you know...
        raise
except:
    pool.terminate(); pool.join()
    raise
else:
    pool.join()
try:
    logging.debug("Sorting results into alignments and summaries")
    sort_start = time.time() # type: float
    alignments, summaries = zip(*results) # type: Tuple[Tuple[alignment.Alignment]], Tuple[Dict[str, Any]]
    logging.debug("Sorting results took %s seconds", round(time.time() - sort_start, 3))
except ExitPool as error: # Handle ExitPool calls for single-threaded map
    sys.exit(error.msg)
```

Does anyone have any idea why multiprocessing is hanging and how I can fix it?

Extra information:

- I'm using Python 2.7.8 on CentOS 7.3.1611; platform and Python version are not changeable
- `crispr_analysis` returns a tuple and dictionary, that are each either empty or have some length based on the inputs
- I have tried omitting the `pool.join()` statements, to no avail
- `ExitPool` is an error that I throw to stop the entire pool in place of`SystemExit`s; multiprocessing normally swallows `SystemExit`s, but I want them to bubble up
- This entire snippet is called from within a function (called `main`)
- This analysis program is called from an easy-install entry script, where the entry point is the `main` function that starts the multiprocessing pool

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/python
  # EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 
  'EdiTyper==1.0.0','console_scripts','EdiTyper'
  __requires__ = 'EdiTyper==1.0.0'
  import sys 
  from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

  if __name__ == '__main__':
      sys.exit(
          load_entry_point('EdiTyper==1.0.0', 'console_scripts', 'EdiTyper')()
      )
  ```

Comment: Does the call to `res.get(timeout)` return within the timeout? Is the `crispr_analysis` function doing anything after it closes whatever files are storing the output?

Comment: @bnaecker Yes, the timeout is roughly 64 hours, while all of `crispr_analysis` takes about 6 minutes on this particular computer, running 8 samples simultaneously. After the final write, `crispr_analysis` assembles the results dictionary and tuple, then logs a message that 'analysis has been completed'. The log message comes *after* results assembling, but before the call to `return` (naturally). I see the final log message before the hang, so I know everything is done.

I've tried several computers with various numbers of workers, and the hanging still occurs.

Comment: Is it possible that one of your processes dies right at the end, without propagating up the stack, as alluded to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24894997/1911852)? I've run into hanging `Pool` with floating point exceptions.